# Express use fails if one path is a substring of another

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

I'm configuring a proxy (http-proxy-middleware) for dev server, using the following configuration

```
app.use(
  /^\/(pathone|pathtwo|pathonetwo)/,
  createProxyMiddleware(...)
)
```

This matches `/pathone` and `/pathtwo` correctly, but `/pathonetwo` is completely ignored and loads the index page instead. How to avoid this? I can't add a `$` at the end because I also need to match paths like `/load/1`.

Edit: using an array of paths (`['/pathone', '/pathtwo', '/pathonetwo']`) works as expected. Is there a bug in how it treats regexps?

Comment: At least `pathonetwo` is regexp is useless because `pathone` triggers the strings that are started with `pathonetwo`. You can play with regexps here https://regex101.com/

Comment: `/pathone` matches and Express doesn't think that `/pathonetwo` starts with `/pathone`. `^\/(pathone(two)?|pathtwo)` should work. Not sure if this is intended. The documentation isn't helpful.